# Freeze and Store Formula Field Count

Tags: apex, visualforce, case, formula-field

I don't know whether this is possible or not.

I have this formula field in Case Object

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Priority, "P4"), 

IF(FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) > 0,TEXT( FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate)) ) & " days ", "") 
& TEXT(23 - FLOOR( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours " 
& TEXT( 59 - ROUND( MOD( (NOW()- CreatedDate)* 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes ", 

"some other" 
)
```

This will return `23 hours 59 minutes` when case inserted with P4 priority and start reducing the count when time goes on.

> I need to freeze the value in formula field when Case Owner Is changed
>   from Queue to User. Meaning that I need to stop the count in formula
>   field with whatever it is when the owner is changing.

Is this possible?

Comment: The best way I see should be to add a flow thanks to process builder. When the case owner is updated, you could insert the current value of the formula to another field. Finally, you could add an another formula which shows your new field if its not null otherwise shows your formula.

Comment: Yes only possible way that I can think of is above one. Created a text field that returns the formula field value when owner is changing(updating in before update trigger event) and in the formula field checking whether new field is null or not null. If not null, returning the value whatever in the new field. If null, just continuing the formula(not stopping the count).